# Problems with setting a class variable in Sprite Kit

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I have just began my first game and I am using Sprite Kit, as it seems easy to start with (I have worked in java before).

My problem is the following.

This block of code:

```
if(self.firstFrame == YES){

    [self.hero1 setHp:100];
    NSLog(@"Hero 1 HP: %i...",[self.hero1 hp]);

    self.firstFrame = NO;
    NSLog(@"First frame passed!");
}
```

Generates this output:

```
2013-11-29 12:36:23.408 SpriteKitGame1[10548:70b] Hero 1 HP: 0...

2013-11-29 12:36:23.408 SpriteKitGame1[10548:70b] First frame passed!
```

No matter what I set `self.hero1 hp` to. Always 0 hp.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Have you allocate and initialise your hero?

Comment: Also, this isn't setting a class variable, this is setting a value for an instance's property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `self.hero1` is nil there, you should allocate and initialize it first.

Be careful because in Obj-C, calling a method on nil doesn't give you any warning/error.